# Storing NSManagedObject in an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to figure out how best to solve my problem. I currently have a table view with cells that users can select and either upload or "Move to the trash" (another table view). The issue is that when I store my NSManagedObject in a swift array to know that they have been selected, swift makes a copy because arrays are value types.

```
    var selectedInspections = [Inspection]()
```

Is there a way to get around this while also keep type safety (I know I could use an NSArray instead, but would prefer not to because of type safety). I would also prefer to not use the table views editing mode.

```
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(sender.center) {
        if let inspection = inspectionFetcher.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Inspection {
            inspection.selected = sender.checked

            if inspection.selected {
                selectedInspections.append(inspection)
            }
            else {
                if let index = selectedInspections.indexOf(inspection) {
                    selectedInspections.removeAtIndex(index)
                }
            }

            // Disable the action button if there are no inspections selected
            actionButton.enabled = selectedInspections.count > 0 ? true : false
        }
    }
```

[image]

Core Data Initialization

```
    guard let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Inspection", withExtension:"momd") else {
        fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
    }

    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL) else {
        fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
    }

    let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)

    managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
        /* The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file.
         This code uses a file named "DataModel.sqlite" in the application's documents directory.
         */
        let storeURL = docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Inspection.sqlite")
        do {
            try psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Then this is what I do to update an attribute on my entity and then save it

```
        // Move all the selected inspections to the trash
        for inspection in self.selectedInspections {
            inspection.inTrash = true
        }

        // Save
        try! self.managedObjectContext.save()

        try! self.inspectionFetcher.performFetch()

        // Empty the selected inspections array
        self.selectedInspections.removeAll()
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?  The array is copied on modify, but this isn't a problem unless you have another class holding a reference of the array.  The objects in the array are not copied.  An `NSMutableIndexSet` may be a better way to store your selections

Comment: When I update an attribute on the NSManagedObject it shows that it is not inserted into the managed object context and so when I save, no changes persist. What is weird though is that the first item in the array will persist, but none of the rest. Also, isn't copy on write only in swift 3 or no?

Comment: No, arrays have always been copy on write in Swift, but it isn't a deep-copy.  The objects *in* the array aren't copied.  If you have a problem with your managed objects, I would be looking at how you are working with them rather than the array.

Comment: Are you using the same `NSManagedObjectContext` for your inspections & trash table views?

Comment: Yes. I have a singleton that initializes the moc and that I hold a strong reference to. I then create separate NSFetchedResultsControllers for both tables. I believe everything else is working. I'll post more code later.